# Is there a way to run a script file every time before my pod is compiled?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have a basic swift script that writes to a file. I need to run that script every time my cocoapods library is compiled.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the podspec file you can do something like this:

```
 s.script_phase = { :name => 'Writing to files', :script => '(./myscript)', :execution_position => :before_compile }
```